# How to find the max of the sums of the absolute values of each column in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I am trying to write a function to find the maximum value of the sums of each value in each column of a matrix without using a numpy function.

For example, given the following array, I want the answer 2.7657527806024733.

```
A = np.array([[0.94369777, 0.34434054, 0.80366952, 0.665736],
              [0.82367659, 0.13791176, 0.6993436, 0.44473609],
              [0.82337673, 0.56936686, 0.46648214, 0.50403736]])
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
def L1Norm(M):
    x = 0
    S = np.shape(M)
    N = S[0]
    P = S[1]
    answer = np.zeros((1, P))
    for j in range(P):
        t = 0
        for i in M:
            t += np.abs(i[j])
        answer = np.append(answer, t)
    s = np.shape(answer)
    n = s[0]
    p = s[1]
    for j in range(p):
        if answer[0][j] > x:
            x = answer[0][j]
    return x
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-e06e08ab836c> in <module>
----> 1 L1Norm(A)

<ipython-input-112-624908415c12> in L1Norm(M)
     12     s = np.shape(answer)
     13     n = s[0]
---> 14     p = s[1]
     15     for j in range(p):
     16         if answer[0][j] > x:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any ideas about how I could fix this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you got `2.7657527806024733`? I checked sums across columns and rows but I don't see this number.

Comment: As with @Georgy, I get 2.7574 and 2.5907 as the max axis sum, across each axis.  Additionally, this does not make sense as a sum is inherently multiple values: "sums of each value ".

Comment: Yes, apologies, the answer I meant to write was 2.59075109. This is the sum of the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres my solve. I loop over the columns and push each sum into an array. Then i loop over that array to find the largest value. It's very verbose but it doesn't use numpy for anything but creating the matrix.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[0.94369777, 0.34434054, 0.80366952, 0.665736],
       [0.82367659, 0.13791176, 0.6993436, 0.44473609],
       [0.82337673, 0.56936686, 0.46648214, 0.50403736]])

matrixShape = np.shape(matrix)

i = 0
j = 0

sumsOfColumns = []

while j < matrixShape[1]:
    sumOfElems = 0
    i = 0
    while i < matrixShape[0]:
        sumOfElems += matrix[i,j]
        i += 1
    sumsOfColumns.append(sumOfElems)
    j += 1

print(sumsOfColumns)

maxValue = 0

for value in sumsOfColumns:
    if value > maxValue:
        maxValue = value

print(maxValue)
```

repl: https://repl.it/@ShroomCode/FrequentFunnyDisplaymanager

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, he was looking for the max value out of the sum of each column, not the sum of the entire matrix. See my answer for clarification.

Comment: Hi Mark, I've tried that but it gives me the wrong answer. Is that giving me the sum along the columns or the rows? Thanks

Comment: Ah right you are @GTBebbo. Sorry Barry, this isn't what you're after. I think GTBebbo's answer is best but if you really must avoid numpy I can try to rework mine for you

Comment: @MarkPotter there is a function in python called `max()` which will return the highest value in an array. Saves you having to use a for loop.

Comment: That's great. Worked perfectly. Thanks very much fro the help.

Answer (score 1):

With numpy you can get each column as an array by using `my_np_array[:,column_number]`

So using this you can do a for loop:

```
sums = []
for i in range(0, np.shape(my_np_array)[0] + 1):
    sums.append(sum(my_np_array[:,i]))

max_sum = max(sums)
```

To solve without numpy, we can go through each row adding each value to its corresponding column tally:

```
import numpy as np

answer = np.array([[0.94369777, 0.34434054, 0.80366952, 0.665736],
       [0.82367659, 0.13791176, 0.6993436, 0.44473609],
       [0.82337673, 0.56936686, 0.46648214, 0.50403736]])

# Convert our numpy array to a normal array
a = answer.tolist()

# list comprehension to initialise list
sums = [0 for x in range(len(a) + 1)]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(a[i])):
        sums[j] += a[i][j]

# Get the max sum
max_sum = max(sums)

print(max_sum)
```

Comment: thanks but I'm trying to do it without using a numpy function

Comment: @Barry O'Keeffe I've updated with a non numpy solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get a max sum of columns, here is a **super simple** approach using a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

vals = np.array([[0.94369777, 0.34434054, 0.80366952, 0.665736],
                 [0.82367659, 0.13791176, 0.6993436, 0.44473609],
                 [0.82337673, 0.56936686, 0.46648214, 0.50403736]])

# Store values to a DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)
# Get the max of column sums.
max_sum = df.sum(axis=0).max()
```

#### As a Function:

```
def max_col_sum(vals):
    max_sum = pd.DataFrame(vals).sum(axis=0).max()
    return max_sum
```

#### Output:

```
2.59075109
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer using zip, np.sum

**Code**

```
def L1Norm(M):
  return max([np.sum(column) for column in zip(*M)])for column in zip(*M)]
```

**Result**

```
2.59075109
```

**Explanation**

List comprehension to loop over data in each column with:

[... for column in zip(*M)]

Sum column values with

```
np.sum(column)
```

Compute Max of list comprehension with:

```
max([...])
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following?-

```
A.sum(0).max()
```

or

```
max(sum(A))
```

Both should give you the desired answer!